# Download only some files in a torrent with rTorrent

Tags: download, rtorrent

Setting the priority to `off` before starting the download doesn't work as expected; `rTorrent` still creates the folder structure and zero sized files for them.

Comment: For reference, [rakshasa/rtorrent#143](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/issues/143) tracks the issue described by this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an intrinsic part of the BT protocol, since it divides all the files' data concatenated into chunks, and doesn't respect file boundaries. Thus, chunks at the start / end of selected files "leak" into the neighboring files.

What you CAN do is automatically delete the incomplete files when removing the item from the client. Namely for rTorrent, by using [rtcontrol --purge](http://code.google.com/p/pyroscope/wiki/RtControlExamples#Pruning_partial_downloads).

Comment: Ok... and what about `rTorrent`?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for a built-in solution since it's a basic feature implemented in many clients (but `rTorrent` I guess...).

Comment: Very likely possible to do it with rT scripting and some f.multicall magic. I'd recommend pre-booking a padded room in the next clinic though, *before* you go about getting all the escaping right.

Comment: Many Bittorrent clients don't create zero byte files nor folder structure. ruTorrent is lacking in many ways but seems to be the default torrent client due to its popular Windows like WebUI client.For example, DHT set to yes doesn't seem to work for me ever, especially if any tracker entries are present. You have options such as Deluge and Tixati for Linux that come with their respective WebUI clients.